# Is there a way to stop Javascript commands being executed in console?

Tags: javascript, security, console

As per the question title.

Although *not* required; I would like to stop people from executing functions on my page via the console... Is this even possible?

I've tried a few things, this is the closest I've come - but this doesn't work :(

```
    window.onresize = function(){
        if((window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight) > 100) {
            //stop commands here?
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        if (typeof console !== "undefined" || typeof console.log !== "undefined") {
            if (window.console && (window.console.firebug || window.console.exception)) {
                    //stop commands here?
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I don't have to disable the console, just function calls made within it - either solution would be fine though ;)

**EDIT2:**
So, to get this right... There is now no way of detecting the console crossbrowser at all?

**EDIT3:**
I've sort of got around it by doing the following, although the JS functions are still in place - the elements that they relate to are not... Not a great fix, but I guess it'll do... :(

```
        setInterval(function() {
            if (!$.browser.mozilla) {
                if((window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight) > 100) {
                    alert("DISABLED!");
                    $('body').remove();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (window.console && (window.console.firebug || window.console.exception)) {
                alert("DISABLED!");
                $('body').remove();
                return false;
            }
        }, 750);
```

Comment: The height check is an especially bad idea. It'll fire for users with too much toolbar space, and won't fire for users running a console in a separate window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good to try detecting console via window width. This may cause some issues on other Browsers, too. If you just want protect your functions:

As you have e.g a button:

```
<button onclick="someFunction()"></button>
```

The someFunction is of course accessable via the console. But if you do not let the user know about your function name, he can not call the function, can he?
See here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//obsfuscate this code
$(function() {
$("#theButton").on("click", someFunction);
})
</script>
<button id="theButton"></button>
```

This is just a possible solution. But rembember, no javascript solution can be 100% secure, because the User knows all of your code, obsfuscated or not.

Comment: (420!) I understand, there used to be a way of detecting the console. But this has been removed also - so is there no work around any more? :(

Comment: As far as I know, not, but why do you need this? maybee there is another way, depends on what you are specially looking for ..

Comment: I have a load of variables being set up in the JS and I don't want the user to be able to change the values using the console.

Comment: JavaScript is client side, so the client can change what he wants. The only way is if you move as much as your code/logic to a server - side script ..

Comment: So, to get this right... There is now **no way** of detecting the console crossbrowser at all?

Comment: There is no *secure* way to find out or preventing the user to change code/variables. Your workarounds work for firefox and chrome if the console is opened **after** the page loads, but you should not trust that the user can not change variables.

Comment: No there isn't. The point @TobiasSpringer is trying to make is that you shouldn't be storing any sensitive data in such a way that it's accessible via javascript.

Comment: aw, that sucks - no way I can base62 encode it so it's not readable?

Comment: You can hide your variables using appropriate function scope - this will make variables private (i.e. not global) and **not easy** to modify. However, a user will always be able to overwrite your code using console to change the scope and expose the variables. You can make this harder by minifying the script.

Comment: Ah ok, I have minified, packed and google-closured my code - i think (by the sound of it) that's all I can do? Unless I can encode it somehow using PHP?

Comment: Okay. This is a basic protection. encoding in PHP does not make sense, because the client has to decode it etc., but you could do a base64encode of course if you want. I would replace $('body').remove() to window.location.href='about:blank' or some other site.